# How to interpret/export large plist data

Tags: xcode, macos, plist

I have plist files that have around 60K lines of code (per BBEdit), and I'm trying to decode some data points saved in these files.  The database company I purchased the software through will not convert my data out to another format (CSV or otherwise) that I can use with a competitor's product, and they will not convert it internally and send me the exported data.  I've started to go through and change one value and then look at the plist and see where the change was made, and I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to find out what the integers are referencing?  I've searched for information on how Plists work, and it seems as though the integer value is referencing some place earlier in the plist document, but as I did not write this program, nor do I have access to source or any help from the company, I'm going to have to reverse engineer this so that I can export the data points I'm interested in, as there are around 100K values I'd like to save.  A royal PITA, but there you have it.  CF$UID appears to be a Core Foundation unique identifier, but that's all I've got.  Any suggestions would be most helpful.

```
<dict>
    <key>$archiver</key>
    <string>NSKeyedArchiver</string>
    <key>$objects</key>
    <array>
    ...some 30-40K lines later
    <dict>
        <key>$class</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CF$UID</key>
            <integer>153</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>stringValue</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CF$UID</key>
            <integer>24</integer>   <--- this is the value that's changing for my particular data point I'm interested in.
        </dict>
```

... so on and so forth, then at the end, something like this.

```
    </array>
    <key>$top</key>
    <dict>
        <key>root</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CF$UID</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>$version</key>
    <integer>100000</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what was done is that [`NSKeyedArchiver`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nskeyedarchiver) was used to serialize an Objective-C object graph to an XML formatted property list. Without the source code (or at least header files) for this code, this is going to be a very painful process. The reason they won't provide this to you as a CSV is that'd make no sense - this is a deeply nested structure which is serializing the in-memory state of the application.

My suggestion is either give up or pour yourself a stiff drink. This is not intended to be directly used by a human.